# How to prevent messages to overlap when using tcp-connection chat

Tags: asynchronous, rust, tcp, command-line-interface, rust-tokio

I wrote a tcp client and a tcp server, and I have a problem: when a user is still writing a message, and an other user sends a message, the two messages will overlap. I'm searching for a way to fix this problem, maybe using an external library.

Overlap example:

`user1` writing message:
[image: user1 writing message]

`user2` sends message:
[image: user2 sends message]

`user1` receiving message:
[image: user1 receiving message]

`user2` receives message that user1 has sent:
[image: user2 receives message that user1 has sent]

client.rs

```rust
use std::io::{stdout, Write};

mod message;
mod user;

use {
    crate::{message::Message, user::User},
    chrono::Local,
    colored::Colorize,
    crossterm::{cursor::MoveToPreviousLine, execute, QueueableCommand},
    rusty_audio::Audio,
    std::{io::BufRead, thread},
    tokio::{
        io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, BufReader},
        net::TcpStream,
        sync::mpsc,
    },
};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // let mut adr_url = String::new();
    // println!("{}", "Enter chat address:".green());
    // std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut adr_url).unwrap();
    // let mut stream = TcpStream::connect(adr_url.trim()).await.unwrap();
    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect("localhost:8080").await.unwrap();

    let (reader, mut writer) = stream.split();

    let mut reader = BufReader::new(reader);
    let mut nickname: String = String::new();
    let mut received_message: Message;

    loop {
        println!("{}", "Enter your nickname: ".red());
        std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut nickname).unwrap();

        let user = User::new(nickname.trim(), (0, 0, 0));
        let message = Message::new("/register", user, 1, "");
        let output = bincode::serialize(&message).unwrap();

        writer.write_all(&output).await.unwrap();

        let mut buffer = vec![0; 1024];

        reader.read(&mut buffer).await.unwrap();

        received_message = bincode::deserialize(&buffer).unwrap();

        if received_message.status == 1 {
            break;
        }
        nickname.clear();
    }

    let me = User::new(&received_message.user.nickname, received_message.user.color);

    let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(10);

    thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut stdin = std::io::stdin().lock();
        loop {
            let mut stdout = stdout();
            let mut line = String::new();
            stdin.read_line(&mut line).unwrap();
            execute!(stdout, MoveToPreviousLine(1)).unwrap();
            if line.trim().len() < 206 && line.trim().len() > 0 {
                print!(
                    "{}: {} - {} ✓\n",
                    "You".red(),
                    line.trim(),
                    Local::now().format("%H:%M").to_string().blue()
                );
                std::io::stdout().flush().unwrap();
                tx.blocking_send(line).unwrap();
            } else {
                stdout.queue(crossterm::style::Print("\x1b[2K\r")).unwrap();
                stdout.flush().unwrap();
                println!("too long or too short");
            }
        }
    });

    let mut audio = Audio::new();
    audio.add("message", "message.wav");
    audio.add("leave", "leave.wav");

    loop {
        let mut buffer = vec![0; 1024];
        tokio::select! {
            result = reader.read(&mut buffer) => {
                result.unwrap();
                let message: Message = bincode::deserialize(&buffer).unwrap();
                let (command, author, color, msg) = (message.command, message.user.nickname, message.user.color, message.message);


                print!("{}: {} - {}\n", author.truecolor(color.0, color.1, color.2), msg, Local::now().format("%H:%M").to_string().blue());

                if command == "/left" {
                    audio.play("leave");
                } else {
                    audio.play("message");
                }
            }

            result = rx.recv() => {
                let line_write = result.unwrap();

                let message: Message;
                if line_write.chars().nth(0).unwrap() == '/' {
                    message = Message::new(line_write.trim(), me.clone(), 1, "");
                } else {
                    message = Message::new("", me.clone(), 1, line_write.trim());
                }
                let output = bincode::serialize(&message).unwrap();
                writer.write_all(&output).await.unwrap();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

server.rs

```rust
mod message;
mod user;

use {
    crate::message::Message,
    rand::prelude::*,
    std::{collections::HashMap, sync::Arc},
    tokio::{
        io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, BufReader},
        net::TcpListener,
        sync::{broadcast, Mutex},
    },
    user::User,
};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let tcp_listener = TcpListener::bind("localhost:8080").await.unwrap();
    let clients: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, User>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));

    let (tx, _rx) = broadcast::channel(10);

    loop {
        let (mut socket, addr) = tcp_listener.accept().await.unwrap();

        let tx: broadcast::Sender<(String, std::net::SocketAddr)> = tx.clone();
        let mut rx: broadcast::Receiver<(String, std::net::SocketAddr)> = tx.subscribe();
        let clients: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, User>>> = Arc::clone(&clients);

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let (reader, mut writer) = socket.split();
            let mut reader = BufReader::new(reader);
            let mut buffer = vec![0; 1024];

            loop {
                tokio::select! {
                    result = reader.read(&mut buffer) => {
                        match result {
                            Ok(_) => {
                                let received_message: Message = bincode::deserialize(&buffer).unwrap();
                                let json_string = serde_json::to_string(&received_message).unwrap();
                                tx.send((json_string, addr)).unwrap();
                            },
                            Err(e) if e.kind() == std::io::ErrorKind::ConnectionReset => {
                                println!("Connection was reset by {:?}", addr);
                                let mut clients = clients.lock().await;
                                println!("{:?}", clients);
                                match clients.get(&addr.to_string()) {
                                    Some(user_left) => {
                                        println!("{:?}", clients);
                                        let server = User::new("server", (100, 100, 100));
                                        let message = Message::new("/left", server, 1, &format!("{} has left", user_left.nickname));
                                        clients.remove(&addr.to_string());

                                        let json_string = serde_json::to_string(&message).unwrap();

                                        tx.send((json_string, addr)).unwrap();
                                    },
                                    None => {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            Err(e) => {
                                println!("An unexpected error occurred: {:?}", e);
                            },
                        }
                    }

                    result = rx.recv() => {
                        let (msg, other_addr) = result.unwrap();
                        let message: Message = serde_json::from_str(&msg).unwrap();
                        let vec = bincode::serialize(&message).unwrap();
                        let (command, user) = (message.command, message.user);

                        println!("{:?}, {:?}", command, user);

                        if command.len() > 0 && addr == other_addr{
                            let mut clients = clients.lock().await;
                            let message: Message;
                            let mut output: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
                            if command == "/register" {
                                if clients.values().any(|val| val.nickname == user.nickname) || user.nickname == "server" || user.nickname == "You" || user.nickname == "you" {
                                    let user = User::new("", (0, 0 ,0));
                                    message = Message::new("", user, 0, "");
                                    output = bincode::serialize(&message).unwrap();

                                } else {
                                    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
                                    let color = (
                                        rng.gen_range(0..=255),
                                        rng.gen_range(0..=255),
                                        rng.gen_range(0..=255),
                                    );

                                    let user = User::new(&user.nickname, color);

                                    clients.insert(addr.to_string(), user.clone());

                                    message = Message::new("", user, 1, "");
                                    output = bincode::serialize(&message).unwrap();

                                }
                            } else if command == "/users" {
                                let server = User::new("server", (100, 100, 100));
                                let nicknames: String = clients.iter()
                                    .filter_map(|(_, user_iter)| if user_iter.nickname != user.nickname { Some(user_iter.nickname.clone()) } else { None })
                                    .collect::<Vec<String>>()
                                    .join(", ");
                                println!("{:?}", nicknames);
                                if nicknames.len() == 0 {
                                    message = Message::new("", server.clone(), 0, "server is empty");
                                    output = bincode::serialize(&message).unwrap();
                                } else {
                                    message = Message::new("", server.clone(), 0, &nicknames);
                                    output = bincode::serialize(&message).unwrap();
                                }
                            }
                            writer.write_all(&output).await.unwrap();
                        } else if addr != other_addr && (command.len() == 0 || command=="/left") {
                            writer.write_all(&vec).await.unwrap();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

user.rs

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct User {
    pub nickname: String,
    pub color: (u8, u8, u8),
}

impl User {
    pub fn new(nickname: &str, color: (u8, u8, u8)) -> Self {
        Self {
            nickname: nickname.to_string(),
            color,
        }
    }
}
```

message.rs

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

use crate::user::User;

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Message {
    pub command: String,
    pub user: User,
    pub status: u8,
    pub message: String,
}

impl Message {
    pub fn new(command: &str, user: User, status: u8, message: &str) -> Self {
        Self {
            command: command.to_string(),
            user,
            status,
            message: message.to_string(),
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to save cursor position with `crossterm` and then delete message, but it didn't work, or maybe I'm using that wrongly. I expect that when the user sends a message when someone else is writing a message, it won't overlap, maybe by deleting the user's input, printing the received message, and then putting the user's input back.

Comment: You most likely want to use some kind of TUI library to distinguish your input and the incoming messages. There's probably some hacky way you could achieve with escape sequences only and other stuff. But I think you're getting a bit too crazy for your simple solution.

Comment: https://github.com/fdehau/tui-rs

Comment: @SeedyROM wdym i'm getting crazy?

Comment: With deleting the input line and re inputting it back at the end. Seems like you're basically recreating TUI libraries.